# Statistical Significance of Time Series Data pre and post intervention

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, intervention-analysis

I am currently working on data in which I have to see the rate of entry of children to a foster home is statistically significant or not before and after a welfare program was implemented. I got the number of entries to the foster home from 2014-2017 (monthly entries) and intervention was implemented in June 2016. Can someone suggest the method to statistically compare the entry rate.

Comment: A $t$-test perhaps?

Comment: If the series is stationary you can test whether or not the average rate is different after the intervention.